# Python: Sorting list containing tuples

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

I am still learning Python and I have been trying to sort this problem for hours but somehow cannot get it working:
Suppose we have a list of tuples containing names and grades:

```
[("Mark", [5,4,1,2,4,3]), ("John", [1,2,3,1,2,1]), ("Patrick", [1,3,5,1,2,4])]
```

And we want to get this output:

```
[("John", [1,2,3,1,2,1]), ("Patrick", [1,3,5,1,2,4]), ("Mark", [5,4,1,2,4,3])]
```

, where the original list is is sorted in ascending order of students' **marks score** (suppose we get **marks score** by discarding the highest mark and adding all remaining marks together).
I.e. John has marks 1,2,3,1,2,1, so we discard mark 3 and add 1+2+1+2+1 together, which gives us 7.

This task wouldnt be problem at all, if I wasnt required to get that output with all their original marks. I wrote this function:

```
def sortedFinalRes(input):
finalRes = 0
sortedRes = []
b = []
for i in range(0, len(input)):
    total = 0
    a = sorted(input[i][1], key = lambda x: x)
    a.pop()
    sortedRes += input[i][0], a
    total = sum(sortedRes[i*2+1])
    b += (sortedRes[i*2], total)
    c = sorted(b, key = lambda x: str(x))
print(sortedRes)
print(b)
```

, where I basically at first sort marks of each student so that I can then discard the highest one by using pop() and then I sum all remaining ones, which gives me marks score. Then I sort it according to marks score, but the output is required to be sorted, but with original marks, not with the mark score. 
Any ideas appreciated! Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can define a scoring function like this:

```
def score(x): sum(x) - max(x)
```

This computes your so-called "marks score" by summing the scores and throwing out the max score. We'll then use it as a key for sorting, making sure to give it the second element of the tuple:

```
In [4]: sorted(d, key=lambda x: score(x[1]))                                                                                                                 
Out[4]: 
[('John', [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1]),
 ('Patrick', [1, 3, 5, 1, 2, 4]),
 ('Mark', [5, 4, 1, 2, 4, 3])]
```

Comment: great answer and snuck it in just before me :P

Comment: Why the double lambdas? Lambdas should never be assigned to variables, it misses the point. How about `sorted(d, key=lambda x: sum(x) - max(x))` instead?

Comment: @tdelaney - `sorted(d, key=lambda x: sum(x[1]) - max(x[1]))` to be exact.  `x` will be the tuples in the list.  But good idea overall.

Comment: @JoranBeasley - oops, I should have looked more closely!

Answer (score 3):

```
def sort_key(item):
    name,scores = item
    return sum(scores)-max(scores)
print sorted(students,key=sort_key)
```

you could easily do it with a single lambda as shown below ... I just did this for added verbosity

Answer (score 1):

you can refuse from max value by `sorted(x[1])[:-1]` that first sort the list and slice from beginning to highest:

```
>>> sorted (l,key=lambda x : sum(sorted(x[1])[:-1]))
[('John', [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1]), ('Patrick', [1, 3, 5, 1, 2, 4]), ('Mark', [5, 4, 1, 2, 4, 3])]
```

answers benchmark :

```
>>> s="""l=[("Mark", [5,4,1,2,4,3]), ("John", [1,2,3,1,2,1]), ("Patrick", [1,3,5,1,2,4])]
... sorted (l,key=lambda x : sum(sorted(x[1])[:-1]))"""
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt=s, number=100000)
0.407818078994751

>>> s="""l=[("Mark", [5,4,1,2,4,3]), ("John", [1,2,3,1,2,1]), ("Patrick", [1,3,5,1,2,4])]
... sorted(l, key=lambda x: sum(x[1]) - max(x[1]))"""
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt=s, number=100000)
0.3033828830718994

>>> s="""l=[("Mark", [5,4,1,2,4,3]), ("John", [1,2,3,1,2,1]), ("Patrick", [1,3,5,1,2,4])]
... def sort_key(item):
...     name,scores = item
...     return sum(scores)-max(scores)
... sorted(l,key=sort_key)"""
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt=s, number=100000)
0.2999439334869385
```

As you can see there no much difference between all the answers , any way Joran Beasley's answer is the best !

Comment: This is actually `nlogn` whereas the other solution is `n`

Comment: @1_CR how you think that using `max` inside `sorted` has `n` order ?

Comment: Actually, if `n` is the size of the outer list, and `m` is the size of the inner, this solution is `O(n m log m + n log n)`, whereas solution with `max` is `O(nm + n log n)`, I believe.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham actually i mean as its key ! but any way im sure that order is not `n`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham The key function `sum(x) - max(x)` takes time `O(m)`, where `m` is the size of the score list. We have to evaluate the key function for each of the `n` entries, giving `O(mn)`. Then we need to sort `n` keys, adding the `O(n log n)`.

Comment: both `sum` and `max` involve a single traversal over an iterable and are therefore `O(n)`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. With the `max` solution, it takes time `O(nm)` to evaluate all of the keys, whereas with this solution it takes time `O(n m log m)`. Both solutions take additional time of `O(n log n)` to sort the outer list. So the `max` solution takes `O(nm + n log n)`, whereas this takes `O(n m log m + n log n)`.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Could you please clarify, specifically, which part you think is wrong, other than just saying that it is wrong?

Comment: @jme, I am not sure I follow you anymore, I was talking about using sorted in the lambda  adding unnecessary overhead.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Right, I think there's some confusion in the fact that the time complexity I gave is for the *whole* shebang, not a single key evaluation. I agree with you that the sort takes `O(m log m)` whereas `sum - max` takes `O(m)` to compute the key for an entry of size `m`. My time complexity just takes into account that there are `n` keys that must be computed.

Comment: @jme, yes I understand you now, running tests using sorted vs max consistently shows sorted takes roughly twice as long, my main point was that sorted should not be used to get the max of a list.

Comment: Thanks for the benchmark Kasra! You should note, though, that the reason people are making a little fuss is that when the size of the inner lists gets big (that is, `("John", [1,2,3,4])` becomes `("John", [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,...,99999])`), sorting starts taking noticeably more time than is needed to solve the problem. So a better benchmark would look at how the solutions scale when both the size of the outer list and the size of the inner list change.

Comment: @jme welcome ,yep surely ! using max is more optimized .